# how can I get camera to take picture and then crop? I am getting crash error

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I am very new to using swift and I have very little coding experience. I have just started learning online at udemy plus some additional tutorials.

I am currently trying to take a picture and then once the picture is taken i can zoom in and out to initiate a crop. Currently this is what I have but Im getting a crash error once I try to run the simulator.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate {

var imageView = UIImageView()

@IBOutlet var camera: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var photoLibrary: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

@IBOutlet var imageDisplay: UIImageView!

@IBAction func photoLibraryAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
     picker.delegate = self
    picker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary

    presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)

}


@IBAction func cameraAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.sourceType = .Camera

    presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)

}


func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    imageDisplay.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage; dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    scrollView.delegate = self

    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height)
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "image")
    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true

    scrollView.addSubview(imageView)

    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.loadImage(_:)))
    tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

}

func loadImage (recognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer){
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary

    self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

}


func imagePickController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

    imageView.image = image
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)

    scrollView.contentSize = image.size

    let scrollViewFrame = scrollView.frame
    let scaleWidth = scrollViewFrame.size.width / scrollView.contentSize.width
    let scaleHeight = scrollViewFrame.size.height / scrollView.contentSize.height
    let minScale = min(scaleHeight, scaleWidth)

    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = minScale
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1
    scrollView.zoomScale = minScale

    centerScrollViewContents()

    picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}

func centerScrollViewContents(){
    let boundsSize = scrollView.bounds.size
    var contentsFrame = imageView.frame

    if contentsFrame.size.width < boundsSize.width{
        contentsFrame.origin.x = (boundsSize.width - contentsFrame.size.width) / 2
    }else{
        contentsFrame.origin.x = 0
    }

    if contentsFrame.size.height < boundsSize.height {

        contentsFrame.origin.y = (boundsSize.height - contentsFrame.size.height) / 2
    }else{
        contentsFrame.origin.y = 0
    }

    imageView.frame = contentsFrame

}

func scrollViewDidZoom(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    centerScrollViewContents()
}

func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return imageView
}

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

and this is the error

```
2016-04-24 14:00:30.148 My Camera App[3127:1150898] -[UIImageView setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x13ed3a2d0
2016-04-24 14:00:30.150 My Camera App[3127:1150898] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x13ed3a2d0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x181e36e38 0x18149bf80 0x181e3dccc 0x181e3ac74 0x181d38d1c 0x10002be24 0x10002c378 0x186f80b40 0x186f80744 0x186f8749c 0x186f84988 0x186ffae8c 0x1872262bc 0x18722a500 0x187227674 0x1837d77ac 0x1837d7618 0x1837d79c8 0x181ded124 0x181decbb8 0x181dea8b8 0x181d14d10 0x186fef834 0x186fe9f70 0x10002fb0c 0x1818b28b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: What's the line that's crashing?

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing this code in simulator for cameraAction method it will not work, You have to use device for that,because simulator doesn't have camera.